# query from id to id in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

i wanna to get query from an id to an id so i used this code:

```
public List<Convers> getConversation(long min,long max){
    List<Convers> queryconvlist = new ArrayList<Convers>();
    Cursor querycursor = database.query(dbHelper.getTableName(1),null, DatabaseHandler.ConvID+" >= "+String.valueOf(min)+" AND " + " < "+String.valueOf(max), null, null, null, null);

    querycursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!querycursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Convers queryconversation = cursorToConv(querycursor);
        queryconvlist.add(queryconversation);       
        querycursor.moveToNext();
    }
    querycursor.close();        
    return queryconvlist;
}
```

but the app has crashed and logcat is

02-15 12:30:06.600: E/SQLiteLog(413): (1) near "<": syntax error

Comment: try `" AND " + DatabaseHandler.ConvID+ " < "+String.valueOf(max)`

Comment: i am tried it but it crashed again and the logcat shows:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main